# Implementing Dictionary in CMS

Tags: .net, database, database-design, architecture, content-management-system

**Scenario:**

I am designing my own CMS application and trying to implement a dictionary functionality in my content per page.

**Problem:**

I designed a table with a word and its definition (like a lookup), and highlight/show those on content in a page. However, there is something which I was trying to achieve i.e. "contextual word definition", for example a word "house" can mean a few things based on a context.

How do I design for this scenario?

Any link/sample design documentation in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using for Context handling of your CMS?

Comment: Are you actually trying to contextually tell if the word "house" is being used as a verb "to house the homeless", or a noun "I own a small house"?

Comment: @RobConklin, Short answer is no. However it is similar, suppose if I have a word "water body" it can be one of many things, i.e. "pond", "river", etc. So it is contextual in terms of how one has to perceive it. I hope my explanation makes sense. However, I will go through links in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for help in starting down [Natural Language Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), particularly [Part Of Speech Tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging).  This is a huge topic, and has a lot of complexity, mostly because computers are actually fairly bad at this, at least compared to humans.

Your best bet is to use some part of the [Stanford Log-linear Part-Of-Speech Tagger](https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordPOSTagger.html) or other NLP processing package to disambiguate the various uses of the word, and match that up with the dictionary declaration.  You will want to tag your definitions with the relevant part-of-speech tags so that the relationship can be established.